# More Descriptive Error Messages From GHC

Tags: haskell, indexing, error-handling, ghci

I ran some code through GHCI, and got this error:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

After a while I went on to fix the bug (which was caused, as you might imagine, by an index that was too large), but I wish GHC would have told me at what line this large index was being evaluated.

Is there a way to either

- A) make GHCI more verbose, or
- B) use a common practice that avoids
  this error somehow (shy of using smaller indexes, of course)

Comment: dependent typing would be a quick fix...

Comment: @ErikAllik No, adding dependent typing to Haskell is quite likely the slowest possible fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can use GHC's profiling facilities to get a kind of stack trace on errors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging#Stack_trace), for example, suppose this is your source file:

```
xs :: [Int]
xs = [1..10]

foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo i = print $ xs !! i

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ foo [1..10]
```

If you compile this with

```
ghc --make -prof -fprof-auto  StackTrace.hs
```

then run it as

```
./StackTrace +RTS -xc
```

then you get

```
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_1_0), stack trace: 
  GHC.List.CAF
  --> evaluated by: Main.foo,
  called from Main.main,
  called from Main.CAF
StackTrace: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

which at least tells you the `main` → `foo` chain.